# проблема с авторизацией через шифрование паролей

Tags: php, база-данных, phpmyadmin

нужно сделать шифрование через password_hash или еще каким-то способом, в файле с регистрацией - это все работает пароли в базу данных заносятся в зашифрованном виде
вопрос в том как сделать чтобы эти пароли можно было использовать при авторизации (скорее всего проблема в условиях в файле login.php, а конкретно не могу понять как взять данные из таблицы sql и внести их в переменную, чтобы сравнивать пароли (может и не в этом, я не знаю))

файл register.php

```
<?php
 
    // session start
    session_start();
 
    // include DB connection
    include('./db.php');
 
    // declaring variables
    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
    $cpassword = "";
 
    // get form data
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $cpassword = $_POST['password'];
    }
 
    //$newPassword = md5(md5($password));
 
    // setting up the target directory where you want to upload your images!
    $target_dir = "../dp/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["dp"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
 
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["dp"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
 
   // Check if file already exists
   if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
 
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["dp"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
 
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
 
 
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["dp"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["dp"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
 
if($name != "" && $email != "" && $password != "" && $cpassword != "") { // if the form fields are not empty!
        
    $checkUser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $checkUserStatus = mysqli_query($conn,$checkUser) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkUserStatus) > 0) { // if user exists!
 
        header('Location: ../main.php?message=Вы уже зарегистрированы!');
 
    } else {
 
        if($password == $cpassword) { // if the password fields match!
        
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 
            $image = basename($_FILES["dp"]["name"]);
            $insertUser = "INSERT INTO users(`name`,`email`,`password`,`dp`) VALUES('$name','$email','$password','$image')";
            //'password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            $insertUserStatus = mysqli_query($conn,$insertUser) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 
            if($insertUserStatus) { // if the user is successfully registered!
  
                header('Location: ../main.php?message=Вы успешно зарегистрированы!');
 
            }  else { // if user is not registered successfully!
 
                header('Location: ../register.php?message=Невозможно зарегистрироваться!');
 
            }
 
        } else { // if password fields dont match!
 
            header('Location: ../register.php?message=Пароли не совпадают!');
 
        }
 
    }
 
 
} else { // if any of the fields are empty!
 
    header('Location: ../register.php?message=Пожалуйста, заполните поля должным образом!');  
 
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    
    // session start
    session_start();
 
    // include DB connection
    include('./db.php');
 
    // declaring variables
    $email = "";
    $pass = "";
 
    // getting form data!
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
 
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
    }
 
 
    if($email != "" && $pass != "") { // if the fields are not empty!
         
        $checkUser = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
        $checkUserStatus = mysqli_query($conn,$checkUser) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 
        if(mysqli_num_rows($checkUserStatus) > 0) { // if user exists!
 
           
      if(password_verify($pass,['password'])){ // if password entered is correct!
              
 
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                header('Location: ../chats.php?message=Вы успешно авторизовались!');
 
            } else {
 
                header('Location: ../main.php?message=Неправильный логин или пароль!');
 
            }
 
 
        } else {
 
            header('Location: ../main.php?message=Невозможно войти в аккаунт!');
 
        }
 
    } else { // if the fields are empty!
 
        header('Location: ../main.php?message=Заполните все поля!');
 
    }
 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

login.php, строка

`if(password_verify($pass,['password']))`

вы передаете массив с 1 один элеме ['password'], туда нужно передавать полученное значение из БД

Comment: я это понимаю, а как это сделать?